# How to check if a postgres user exists?

Tags: postgresql, shell, user-management

`createuser` allows creation of a user (ROLE) in PostgreSQL. Is there a simple way to check if that user(name) exists already? Otherwise createuser returns with an error:

```
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "USR_NAME" already exists
```

UPDATE: The solution should be executable from shell preferrably, so that it's easier to automate inside a script.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'
```

And in terms of command line (thanks to Erwin):

```
psql postgres -tXAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'"
```

Yields 1 if found and nothing else.

That is:

```
psql postgres -tXAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'" | grep -q 1 || createuser ...
```

Comment: Do you remember what's the built-in command-line utility to execute SQL? In the end I'd prefer to execute and retrieve the result from shell if possible.

Comment: `psql` is the command. But if you're talking about `createuser` command line utility (you obviously do, I didn't notice the lack of space in `create user` at first), then it may be easier just to ignore the exit status and redirect output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @m33lky: Or you could test the return value of this command in the shell (as postgres user):  `psql postgres -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'"`. Yields `1` if found and nothing else.

Comment: Haha, I just did that in a little more ugly fashion: `echo "SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME';" | psql | grep -c USR_NAME`. Add your solution as an answer without "postgres" after psql.

Comment: @m33lky: I only wrote a comment, because I think Michael deserves the credit on this one. He contributed the main part. And he proved to be a good sport in the past. :) Maybe Michael wants to incorporate it in his answer?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, okay, to make us even :)

Comment: He recommended directing output to /dev/null ;D

Comment: @m33lky, I recommended devnulling `createuser` output, not `psql`'s.

Comment: I'd recommend including the `-X` flag to prevent the `.psqlrc` file from being read. It is pretty common for that file to turn on `\timing` which is likely to create false positives with the `grep -q 1` since timing values will often include a `1`. So, `psql postgres -tXAc ...`.

Comment: @jbranchaud, makes sense. I personally never once created a `.psqlrc` file for myself, didn't think of it :)

Answer (score 13):

Following the same idea than to [check if a db exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549270/check-if-database-exists-in-postgresql-using-shell)

```
psql -t -c '\du' | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -qw <user_to_check>
```

and you can use it in a script like this:

```
if psql -t -c '\du' | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -qw <user_to_check>; then
    # user exists
    # $? is 0
else
    # ruh-roh
    # $? is 1
fi
```

Comment: This would generate a larger query result than answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8546783/107158.  However, unlike that answer, this one would survive a rename to system table `pg_roles`, but not a change to command `\du`.  Which is most likely not to change?

Answer (score 3):

`psql -qtA -c "\du USR_NAME" | cut -d "|" -f 1`

`[[ -n $(psql -qtA -c "\du ${1}" | cut -d "|" -f 1) ]] && echo "exists" || echo "does not exist"`

Answer (score 3):

To do this entirely within a single psql command:

```
DO $$BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'USR_NAME')
THEN CREATE ROLE USR_NAME;
END IF;
END$$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps those of you who might be doing this in **python**.
I created a complete working script/solution on a GitHubGist--see URL below this code snippet.

```
# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546759/how-to-check-if-a-postgres-user-exists
check_user_cmd = ("SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='%s'" % (deis_app_user))

# our create role/user command and vars
create_user_cmd = ("CREATE ROLE %s WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD '%s'" % (deis_app_user, deis_app_passwd))

# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488175/simplify-database-psycopg2-usage-by-creating-a-module
class RdsCreds():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=%s user=%s host=%s password=%s" % (admin_db_name, admin_db_user, db_host, admin_db_pass))
        self.conn.set_isolation_level(0)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)
        return self.cur.rowcount > 0

    def close(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()

db = RdsCreds()
user_exists = db.query(check_user_cmd)

# PostgreSQL currently has no 'create role if not exists'
# So, we only want to create the role/user if not exists 
if (user_exists) is True:
    print("%s user_exists: %s" % (deis_app_user, user_exists))
    print("Idempotent: No credential modifications required. Exiting...")
    db.close()
else:
    print("%s user_exists: %s" % (deis_app_user, user_exists))
    print("Creating %s user now" % (deis_app_user))
    db.query(create_user_cmd)
    user_exists = db.query(check_user_cmd)
    db.close()
    print("%s user_exists: %s" % (deis_app_user, user_exists))
```

[Provides idempotent remote (RDS) PostgreSQL create role/user from python without CM modules, etc.](https://gist.github.com/cmcconnell1/8d5fa5d7fe000f92213b0f34374428f8)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8546783/11159476), that unfortunately did not work for me (error on direct `psql` call), I then did something like this:

```
if ! echo "SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='USR_NAME'" | psql -h localhost -U postgres | grep -E "[1-9][0-9]* rows"; then
  # User not found, create it
  if ! echo "CREATE USER USR_NAME WITH PASSWORD 'USR_NAME' CREATEDB SUPERUSER" | psql -h localhost -U postgres; then
    echo "Error creating USR_NAME"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Even if I think `grep -E "1 rows"` is safe here since we should not have more that one user of same name, I prefer keeping `grep -E "[1-9][0-9]* rows"` to get a generic "I got 1 or more result(s)" returning success.
And I put `exit 1` if it fails because I'm on a script that needs this user created to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

### A complete snippet for PHP:

- and furthermore, it might be better to mention the system catalog/table name "pg_roles" in front of the column name "rolname". Like this: "pg_roles.rolname".
- and to mention it, because it confused me: it is really spelled "rolname" and not "rolename".

```
// PHP Version 8.1.13
// PostgreSQL 15

try {
    // database connection
    $pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbuserkeyword, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    if ($pdo) { // went fine

        // a query to ask if user available in table (system catalog) "pg_roles" and column "rolname"
        $myResult = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE pg_roles.rolname='{$theuseriamlookingfor}'");

        // retrieve the values from response in an Array
        $myResult = $myResult -> fetchAll();

        // output the first value from that Array
        echo $myResult[0]["rolname"];
    } 

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // output the error-message
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```