# Test a return value in bash

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am trying to write a bash script that creates and sets up a postgres database if it does not already exist.  Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549270/check-if-database-exists-in-postgresql-using-shell), I've got to this script:

```
if [ `psql -l | grep mydb | wc -l` -eq 1]
then
    echo "Database exists"
else:
    echo "Creating database"
    ...
fi
```

But it always returns with `"Database exists"`, regardless of whether the database is there or not.  I've also tried `` [ "` psql -l | grep mydb | wc`" == "1" ] ``, but it gives the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** The output of `psql -l` and `psql -l | grep mydb` are:

```
$ psql -l
                                       List of databases
    Name    |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 geoserver  | adminhgv7rj4 | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres   | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 project_db | gis_group    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0  | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(6 rows)
$ psql -l | grep mydb
$
```

Comment: What is the output of `psql -l`? And `psql -l | grep mydb`?

Comment: If you just want to test whether that `grep` found something or not, you should use `if psql -l | grep -q mydb; then …`.

Comment: @fedorqui I've run those manually to make sure that they are giving the correct output.  The output from `psql -l | grep mydb | wc -l` is `0`.  If I manually create the database it is `1`, and if I drop it it goes back to `0`.

Comment: @Alfe That doesn't work either.  It prints the `grep` result then `Database exists`.

Comment: You have a strange `grep` if it prints anything when given the option `-q` (for quiet).  Have you really given that option?

Comment: But what's the output of `psql -l | grep mydb` alone? And just `psql -l`?

Comment: @Alfe Where do you see `-q`?  I haven't used it.

Comment: @aquavitae then you should read my comment more carefully.  That `-q` is an option given to `grep`.  I propose to use copy & paste to prevent such simple errors.

Comment: In the question you are linking there is an alternative: `psql -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -w <db_name> | wc -l`. Give a try to it, as it is safer because it just checks the first column.

Comment: @Alfe Sorry, you're right - I missed it!  And it works, thanks!  I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test whether that grep found something or not, you should use

```
if psql -l | grep -q mydb
then
  …
```

Answer (score 2):

The question referred by you includes alternatives that don't require multiple pipes, and seem simpler.

You could say:

```
( createdb mydb || { echo "creating.." ; false; } ) && echo "database exists"
```

This is essentially equivalent to saying:

```
if ! createdb mydb; then
  echo "Creating database";
else
  echo "Database exists"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've got a whole list of commands I need to run if the database doesn't exist, and I can't wrap them all like that.

Comment: @aquavitae I'm not sure what you mean by `I can't wrap them all like that` -- you could insert multiple statements in any of the blocks.

Comment: Oh, you mean use the second form, and include the extra code in below the `echo`s.  Yes, that could work!

Comment: @aquavitae: .. or you could invoke a function (instead of echo "..." ; other statements ) that has multiple statements and outputs a proper return code when it finishes. Could improve readability ? ie : `( createdb mydb || { func1 ; } ) && func2` (as devnull proposed. Note however that func2 occurs if **either** createdb or func1 worked! and 'echo' always works! )

Comment: @devnull: in the current form `( createdb mydb || { echo "creating.." ; } ) && echo "database exists"`  I believe it will always output `database exists` (sometimes preceded by `creating...`) as the `&& echo "database exists"` occurs if either `createdb mydb` OR `echo "creating..."` outputs a 0, and echo will output 0.Therefore it is **not** equivalent to the if/then/else/fi you put underneath

Comment: @OlivierDulac Yes, the shorter form should have been: `( createdb mydb || { echo "creating.." ; false; } ) && echo "database exists"` to be __equivalent__ to the if/then/else/fi variant.

Comment: @devnull: it's better indeed. But I'd `{echo "createdb failed" ; false;}` or `{echo "you need to create mydb" ;false; }` instead of `{echo "creating..."` ; false; }` ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac error messages can be customized as per user needs.  FWIW, one might even localize those.  Appreciate your inputs, nevertheless.