# bash script - check for specific string in output is failing

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE template0;"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    if [ $? = 'ERROR:  database "test" already exists' ]; then
         echo OK
    else
         echo FAIL
    fi
fi
```

It's currently failing with the following error:

```
testbox:/tmp# sh test.sh 
ERROR:  database "test" already exists
FAIL
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.  I need it to return "OK" for this specific error.  Any other errors should print out a FAIL. 
Can you tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT 1

I've modified the code to capture the output, not just rc:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE template0;")
ret=$?

if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo OK
else
    if [[ $output == 'ERROR:  database "test" already exists' ]]; then
         echo OK
    else
         echo FAIL
    fi
fi
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  database "test" already exists
sh: ERROR:  database "test" already exists: unknown operand
FAIL
```

Comment: `$?` represents just the integer exit code not the output of your `psql` command. You need to grab the output and check.

Comment: @anubhava ok. can you give me an example?

Comment: @Happydevdays: try adding `echo $?` immediately after the `psql` command, and you'll see what anubhava means (it'll just print a number, probably "1"). Then add a second `echo $?`, and you'll see that one print "0" because the first `echo` command succeeded, and therefore exited with a status code of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$?` represents just the integer exit code not the output of your `psql` command. You need to grab the output of `psql` command and check in `if` condition.

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE template0;" 2>&1)
ret=$?

if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo OK
else
    if [[ $output == *'already exists'* ]]; then
         echo OK
    else
         echo FAIL
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I've changed first line to `output=$(psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE template0;" 2>&1)` so that we capture stderr also from `psql` command

Comment: That works now.  Thank you.  What can i google to better understand the "2>&1" at the end of the first line?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr to file descriptor `1` which is `stdout`

Comment: @Happydevdays [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/) is a great resource.  [Beginner's guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html).  [Advanced guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html). And more specifically, [the I/O redirection topic you're asking about](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#IO-REDIRECTION).

Comment: @anubhava I am having a similar issue but the `return code is always 0`      `content=$(java -jar ${jarFilePath} -u ${username},${password} -n ${host} -c "${val_query}") 
rc=$?`  If the `val_query` has any syntax issue then how can I capture the error

Answer (score 0):

The `$?` will output an integer based on exit code of last command executed.
when the database exists it will be `1` returned. Thats why your script is failing.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way if checking if a database exists can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549270/check-if-database-exists-in-postgresql-using-shell).

Based on that output you can create your database and return somehting meaningful.