# Test authenticate postgres user without login

Tags: postgresql

I created a role with login permission, but I can't login with it, I get:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

I have confirmed by `select * from pg_roles` that the role exists and has login permission.

I suspect an error in my db set up script caused it to be created with a different password to what I believed it was set to.

I realise that you cannot lookup the existing password of a role but I figure there ought to be a function which can be used to tell if a plaintext matches password for a role?

eg in a web app when we store passwords in the db they are salted and hashed... you can't tell what is the password from looking at that, but you can take a new plaintext and run the password hashing on it and say if the hash of your plaintext matches the stored password.

Is there something like that for psql?

I found other SO questions, eg [Authenticate PostgreSQL user and password without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927168/authenticate-postgresql-user-and-password-without-database), about how to check password but they suggest trying to login with that role from commandline, which I can't do ("password authentication failed").

In my case I realise I should just trust the error message and assume role was created with wrong password... but let's imagine I'd created a role without `LOGIN` permission - this way of checking wouldn't be possible.

There are other ways to debug my script of course, but I am curious if such a 'password check' function exists.

For example, I found these in the docs:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html
...but they are provided as helpers for building applications on top of Postgres - it is not clear if they are used by Postgres iteself for role passwords.

Comment: You say you cannot test on commandline, so I presume you are using some web interface to connect to PostgreSQL to test this? If so, it might be that your access rules for `host` in your `pg_hba.conf` are letting you login via `peer` (Unix user credentials) instead of via `md5` (The actual database credentials). Do you have any means to access the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: I can login with superuser on the command-line, but not with the role I created for my web app... I have since confirmed (by dropping and recreating role) it was a problem with password set to wrong value ...but I'd still like to know if there is a suitable function for checking psql passwords

Comment: to whoever left the 'close' vote... please read the question more carefully - I am not asking for vague help with my login problem, I'm asking for specific solution for checking a plaintext against an existing role password in psql console (or via SQL)

Comment: Well, PostgreSQL user passwords are stored in md5 and (if I remember correctly) use the username as a salt. I don't think there is a function directly, but knowing the algorithm and the salting, you should be able to check if a given plain text password is the same as what is stored using (as you already found) the `md5` hashing function of the `pg_crypto` package.

Comment: If you can find that described in the docs please post as an answer... if I do `SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='myrole'` it is displayed as`********`, so I can't even see the hash that I need to compare to.

Comment: I guess what you want is: `SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname='myrole';`. [From the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-authid.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As posted in the comments, this answer is to compare a given plain text password with a stored md5 hashed PostgreSQL role password. I consider this somewhat of a hack, but let's do it anyway.

The following can be done with the "plain" `md5()` function in core PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL's role passwords are hashed with `md5` and salted with the role name. As an added bonus, they are prefixed with 'md5'. So a query to match a password to a role would be

```
select * from pg_authid WHERE rolpassword = 'md5' || md5('the-plain-text-password' || 'the-role-name');
```

The important bit (of course) is:

```
'md5' || md5('the-plain-text-password' || 'the-role-name');
```

Where we concatenate a string "md5" with an `md5` hash of the plain text password and the role name as the salt.

Comment: great, this works! I didn't even have to install pgcrypto... the builtin `md5` function works fine with exact syntax above http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Good to hear. Ah, I may have been to hasty to recommend `PGCrypto` then, I will test and alter my answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: it's worth noting also that [`pg_authid` docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-authid.html) helpfully describe exactly the method used to hash the passwords

Comment: Correct. I have adapted my answer, which makes it simpler. You indeed don't need `PGCrypto` at all.

Comment: Note that only a superuser can access that table, on RDS you have an RDS_SUPERUSER which is not the same thing. So you're out of luck there without actually attempting the login.